# Smooth scroll + remove active class won't work together

Tags: jquery

I have a remove/add active class and smooth scroll script on my one pager. One script would work but when I combine them, the remove/add active class won't work anymore.

[link here](http://theblisteringvoid.com/mockboard/)

I have this script

```
    $(function() {
        $(".nav li").on("click", function() {
          $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });

    $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top-50
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your scripts inside the same $(function() wrapper:

```
$(function() {
    $(".nav li").on("click", function() {
      $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });

  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top-50
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: The remove active class still won't work. Please see my sample here: http://theblisteringvoid.com/mockboard/